# Is there an in-game list that shows all armor pieces and requirements to unlock them?

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

So in Advanced Warfare there's probably a good amount of armor, clothes, etc. And I wondered if there's a list in-game that shows them all and how to unlock them. From what I've seen there's only the "challenges" list (sorted by type of challenge, not armor) that shows armor as reward for completing a challenge (if you get one), but I could not find a list with all armor.

If really no list exists in-game, can anyone link a good website? I searched some CoD wikis, but they all seem to be sorting challenges the same way CoD itself does.

Comment: I think most items are unlocked at random through supply drops.  I don't believe the list of things unlocked from challenges would be the same. It may be too soon to find a complete list, I didn't see anything relevant at a quick search.

Comment: I found something for weapons, but not armor.

Comment: Quite simply, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You are right there are no lists for Armour unlocking. The only list you will get is in challenges under operations. So far you can get the complete set of K.V.A Assassin outfit, That is under Killer. There are also other Armour but it is shown under Weapons. [That Armour is full Diamond](http://callofdutyplay.com/cod-advanced-warfare-diamond-exo-suit-diamond-armor-guns-advanced-warfare-news/).

Then here is a [list of everything BUT ARMOUR](http://mp1st.com/2014/11/02/everything-call-duty-advanced-warfare/)!

Answer (score -1):

Unfourtunately there is little information out right now. Later as the game progresses we might be able to get more information. However this is what I managed to scrape up:

From this [information site](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/19537/20141106/call-duty-advanced-warfare-rank-up-fast-best-camos-more.htm):

Get More Supply Drops
About the 3 Types of Supply Drops

- Weapon Loot (custom weapon variants)
- Character Gear (changes your appearance; doesn't affect gameplay)
- Reinforcements (single-use bonuses)

This one comes with a disclaimer: It's very likely a glitch that Sledgehammer Games will get around to fixing. But use it now while you still can, and you'll score some sweet gear.
YouTuber Quadmft discovered that in multiplayer levels, if you die when you first enter, it gives you a Supply Drop. He says it works every time, but this is the important part: don't kill another player before you die. Enter the level, let someone kill you, and respawn. You'll immediately get a fresh Supply Drop.

For Camo:

- Gold: kill 50 enemy players while using no weapon attachments
- Diamond: complete every camo challenge for the weapon in question
- Royal: complete every camo challenge for all the weapons in this class

Read more: http://www.techtimes.com/articles/19537/20141106/call-duty-advanced-warfare-rank-up-fast-best-camos-more.htm#ixzz3KgrjzlCn